# Why error is showing on click of button?

Tags: objective-c

Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates when I am using  UIActionsheet on click of button in ios? Why?

```
- (IBAction)btnAboutUsActions:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                                destructiveButtonTitle: nil
                                                     otherButtonTitles: @"Achievment",
                                                                        @"Brown Story", nil];
    actionSheet.tag = 100;

    [actionSheet showFromRect: sender.frame inView: sender.superview animated: YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `alertController`

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:confirmText message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *achievment = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Achievment"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:nil];
[alert addAction: achievment];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
[alert.view layoutIfNeeded]
```

Comment: Thank You for Suggestion. but, i want to use ActionSheet then?because I have to perform multiple option on click of button And multiple option view show exact  below button.!!!

Comment: Try to write `[actionSheet.view layoutIfNeeded]` after showing it.

Comment: i already tried it!   [actionSheet layoutIfNeeded];  its not working!

Comment: actually i'm try to open link in web view on click of UIActionsheet button!!